# Django app runs fine at first on mod_wsgi Apache2 then stops responding how do I troubleshoot issue

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, apache2.4

I have not used Django in many years. I recently found a niche to use it, created app, and it runs fine using runserver, no issues. I am trying to set it up to run on Apache stack with mod_wsgi, and when I start the Apache server it seems to run for a short time then stops "responding" to requests. I am sure there are things I am missing, have been scouring to find logging etc. cannot figure out why it is not running. Have tried the runserver from the same set of directories and no issues.

Every time I stop and restart it seems to run fine, but after a while it just quits responding. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried making changes to Apache, found somethings like adding WSGIApplicationGroup {%GLOBAL} this did not change anything. I have been watching htop far from using up processors, ram etc.
Running Apache 2.4.52 mod_wsgi 4.9.0 Python3.10 Django version 4.2.3.